# How do I print 2 variable alternatively n number of time

Tags: python

I got my homework problem. I need to input 2 variables and print them out alternatively n number of times without using if-else or loop statement.

```
 a = input() #character
 b = input() #character
 n = input("n ")
```

I want to print out string of "ababa"

e.g.

```
a = "#" 

b = "%"


n = 5
```

Expected output: `#%#%#`

or

```
n = 4
```

Expected output: `#%#%`

Comment: What code did you try to solve your problem, and where did it fail?

Comment: I just don't know print() parameter. I knew something like print(a * 3) but that's only for single variables right?

Comment: You can also concatenate strings with `+` and combine that with the `*`

Comment: ok I just tried print((a+b) * n) and it just worked. Thanks.

Comment: `print((a+b) * n)` didn't worked because if I put n = 3 It gave me "ababab". I wanted to print out just n characters.

Comment: There is the modulo operator `%` for numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have shown some effort in your comments I will give an answer. This uses the `//` integer division and `%` modulus operators. Note that I had to convert the value of `n` to an integer.

```
a = input("a? ")  # character
b = input("b? ")  # character
n = int(input("n? "))

print((a + b) * (n // 2) + a * (n % 2))
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. The  n % 2  is to check if there is a remainder so it prints out the last "a", right?

Comment: @RustinSpencer: Yes, correct. If `n` is even then `n % 2` is zero so `a * (n % 2)` is the empty string, which is not visible. If `n` is odd then `n % 2` is one so `a * (n % 2)` is the last occurrence of character `a`. If no one gives a better answer, please accept this answer (if it actually answers your question) by clicking the checkmark near the top-left of the answer. That is better than saying thanks in a comment. It also helps others to see that your question was answered.